# Microsoft Graph API - get drive "Url specified is invalid."

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am facing a weird issue with microsoft's graph api.
I am trying to retrieve files stored on Sharepoint. I don't know what the issue is and I have tried a lot of different things:

Call to get all drives for the site works and returns a list of all available drives:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/site.sharepoint.com,<id>,<id>:/teams/myTeam:/drives
```

Via the previous endpoint I can extract the `id` for that drive with which I would then like to retrieve drive details (and in consequence all children of that drive):

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/site.sharepoint.com,<id>,<id>:/teams/myTeam:/drives/<driveId>
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/site.sharepoint.com,<id>,<id>:/teams/myTeam:/drives/<driveId>/root
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/site.sharepoint.com,<id>,<id>:/teams/myTeam:/drives/<driveId>/root/children
```

But all 3 above endpoints throw a `400 Bad Request Error` with message: `Url specified is invalid.`

Additional information:
My access token has the following scopes: `Sites.FullControl.All User.Read profile openid email`

I am able to retrieve an individual drive item through the list endpoints (but the folder structure is quite complex and I need to list several layers of folders/files - this is why I believe the syntax with drive would be a lot more convenient):

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/site.sharepoint.com,<id>,<id>:/teams/myTeam:/lists/<list-id>/items/<item-id>/driveItem
```

via the field `parentReference` I am also able to fetch the `driveId` and even the relative path (`/drives/<drive-id>/root:`) but I also have no idea how I would get the content from that.

Help is greatly appreciated as I have been stuck for a long time now - thank you!

Comment: Try something like `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/site.sharepoint.com,<id>,<id>/drives/driveid/root/children`

Comment: Awesome that worked - thank you very much!

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please accept it so that it would be helpful to others who look for the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the below HTTP call.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/site.sharepoint.com,<id>,<id>/drives/driveid/root/children`

It worked for me.